# PHP conditional script issue

Tags: php, conditional-content

I'm have the 2 seperate block of codes as shown below and the one below doesn't work except if I cut off the first one. Any ideas what the problem could be?

**Conditinal script**

```
<?php { ?>

    <?php

        if ( is_front_page() ) {

        get_template_part('home-page-content');

                    } elseif ( is_page('archives')) {


           get_template_part('archives');

    }
    else

        get_template_part('secondary-page-content');


     ?> 
        <?php } ?>
```

**Second block of script**

```
 <div id="footer">
     <?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "biz_code", true); ?> 
        </div>
```

Comment: We need more information to assist.  What is the problem exactly?  You mention "doesn't work" which can be interpreted many ways.

Comment: Can you indent your code correctly? It's difficult to read

Comment: Also can you enable error logging and tell us what the error message PHP gave you was?

Answer (score 3):

You have a lot of PHP tag spam, e.g.:

```
?><?php
```

This is bad, confusing, makes your code difficult to read, and a waste of your time to type. It's the difficulty reading your code that has lead to your problem, including the lack of indentation. These are important, and any good editor will do them for you effortlessly.

If we remove the PHP tag spam, and indent correctly, we get this:

```
<?php
{
    if ( is_front_page() ) {
        get_template_part('home-page-content');
    } else if ( is_page('archives') ) {
        get_template_part('archives');
    } else
        get_template_part('secondary-page-content');
}
?>
```

Firstly, there is a set of braces surrounding the whole thing, serving no purpose ( except maybe to confuse ). Remove these, giving us:

```
<?php
if ( is_front_page() ) {
    get_template_part('home-page-content');
} else if ( is_page('archives') ) {
    get_template_part('archives');
} else
    get_template_part('secondary-page-content');
?>
```

Finally, we have coding standards, so lets put braces around the final else statement:

```
<?php
if ( is_front_page() ) {
    get_template_part('home-page-content');
} else if ( is_page('archives') ) {
    get_template_part('archives');
} else {
    get_template_part('secondary-page-content');
}
?>
```

We can go further, those are a lot of calls to `get_template_part`, what if we only called that function once?

```
<?php
$template = 'secondary-page-content';
if ( is_front_page() ) {
    $template = 'home-page-content';
} else if ( is_page('archives') ) {
    $template = 'archives';
}
get_template_part( $template );
?>
```

However, all of this implies that you've overloaded one template with too much responsibility. I suggest you look at the template hierarchy, that way we can use the `frontpage.php` template to remove half of that if statement.

Comment: Nowell I've amended the script with your corections but the problem I'm facing is different. The uppr block of code works but the one below doesn't work untill I cut off the upper one.

Comment: Then you haven't given us enough information, ***please activate error logging and tell us what the PHP error message is***, also what file is this in? What's inside those template files you're including?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a PHP error to me with random braces:

```
<?php { ?>
<?php } ?>
```

This should be:

```
<?php
..code here..
?>
```